# Inheritance and type parameters of Traversable

Tags: generics, scala, scala-2.8, scala-collections

I'm studying the source code of the Scala 2.8 collection classes. I have questions about the hierarchy of `scala.collection.Traversable`. Look at the following declarations:

```
package scala.collection
    trait Traversable[+A]
        extends TraversableLike[A, Traversable[A]] 
        with GenericTraversableTemplate[A, Traversable]

    trait TraversableLike[+A, +Repr]
        extends HasNewBuilder[A, Repr]
        with TraversableOnce[A]

package scala.collection.generic
    trait HasNewBuilder[+A, +Repr]

    trait GenericTraversableTemplate[+A, +CC[X] <: Traversable[X]]
        extends HasNewBuilder[A, CC[A] @uncheckedVariance]
```

Question: Why does `Traversable` extend `GenericTraversableTemplate` with type parameters `[A, Traversable]` - why not `[A, Traversable[A]]`? I tried some experimenting with a small program with the same structure and got a strange error message when I tried to change it to `Traversable[A]`:

```
error: Traversable[A] takes no type parameters, expected: one
```

I guess that the use of the `@uncheckedVariance` annotation in `GenericTraversableTemplate` also has to do with this? (That seems like a kind of potentially unsafe hack to force things to work...).

*edit* - found some useful answers about the annotation in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454281/when-is-uncheckedvariance-needed-in-scala-and-why-is-it-used-in-generictraversa) (it is because `GenericTraversableTemplate` is used for both mutable and immutable collections which have different variance).

Question: When you look at the hierarchy, you see that `Traversable` inherits `HasNewBuilder` twice (once via `TraversableLike` and once via `GenericTraversableTemplate`), but with slightly different type parameters. How does this work exactly? Why don't the different type parameters cause an error?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The reason is the `CC` parameter in the `GenericTraversableTemplate` trait.  Unlike a normal type parameter which has kind `*` (pronounced "type"), this parameter has type `* => *` (pronounced "type to type").  In order to understand what this means, you first need to have a little background about kinds.

Consider the following snippet:

```
val a: Int = 42
```

Here we see `42`, which is a *value*.  Values have intrinsic types.  In this case, our value is `42` and the type is `Int`.  A type is something like a category which encompasses many values.  It says something about the values which are possible for variable `a`.  For example, we know that `a` cannot contain the value `"foobar"`, because that value has type `String`.  Thus, values are sort of like the first level of abstraction, while types are one level above values.

So here's the question: what's stopping us from taking this one step further?  If values can have types, why can't types have "something" above them?  That "something" is called a *kind*.  Kinds are to types what types are to values, generic categories which restrict what sort of *types* can be described.

Let's look at some concrete examples:

```
type String
type Int
type List[Int]
```

These are types, and they all have kind `*`.  This is the most common kind (which is why we call it "type").  In practice, most types have this kind.  However, some do not:

```
type List     // note: compile error
```

Here we have the type constructor `List`, but this time we "forgot" to specify its type parameter.  As it turns out, this is actually a type, but one of a different kind.  Specifically, `* => *`.  As the notation is meant to imply, this kind describes a type which takes another type of kind `*` as a parameter, producing a new type of kind `*` as a result.  We can see this in the first example, where we passed the `Int` type (which has kind `*`) to the `List` type constructor (which has kind `* => *`), producing the type `List[Int]` (which has kind `*`).

Returning to `GenericTraversableTemplate`, let's look again at the declaration:

```
trait GenericTraversableTemplate[+A, +CC[X] <: Traversable[X]]
```

Notice how the `CC` type parameter takes a parameter of its own, but that parameter is not defined by any other type parameter in the declaration?  This is Scala's rather clumsy way of saying that `CC` must be of kind `* => *` (just like `a` must be of type `Int` in our earlier example).  "Normal" type parameters (such as `A`) are always of kind `*`.  By forcing `CC` to be of kind `* => *`, we're effectively telling the compiler that the only valid types which can be substituted for this parameter must be themselves of kind `* => *`.  Thus:

```
type GenericTraversableTemplate[String, List]        // valid!
type GenericTraversableTemplate[String, List[Int]]   // invalid!
```

Remember, `List` is of kind `* => *` (exactly what we need for `CC`), but `List[Int]` has kind `*`, so the compiler rejects it.

For the record, `GenericTraversableTemplate` itself has a kind, specifically: `(* x (* => *)) => *`.  This means that `GenericTraversableTemplate` is a type which takes two types as parameters -- one of kind `*`, the other of kind `* => *` -- and produces a type of kind `*` as a result.  In our example above, `GenericTraversableTemplate[String, List]` is one such result type, and as we computed, it is of kind `*` (it takes no parameters).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this so clearly! I'd heard about "kinds" before but didn't really understand what they mean until now.